# Resultset's first row is skipped when while(rs.next) is executed in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to get a result set of a SQL query in a java class. The problem is that the first row of my table is never displayed on my UI. So I debugged it.

When the while loop is first executed, `while(rs.next)` line executes then it does not go in to the loop, return backs to the beginning of while loop and executes `while(rs.next)` line again, now it goes into the while loop and sets the result set.

But since it does not go into the loop in the first time, the first row of my table is not set into the result set.

I could not find the problem here.

I tried `do{} while(rs.next)` but some times it throws exhausted result set exception

```
    String SQL_QUERY = select * from my_table;
Statement stt = null;
stt= conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(SQL_QUERY);
if (rs != null) {
    rs.absolute(startRow); // I need to go to some specific row according to users request that is why I used this
} 

while(rs.next){
    // rs.getString...
}
```

Comment: Well you go to the startRow, then you call next(). So obviously, you're now at startRow + 1.

Comment: Since there is the same bug in all three answers, it might be worth mentionning that `next` is a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()), so you need to write `rs.next()`, not `rs.next`.

Comment: You may want to consider paging through the query instead of retrieving everything and then page in the result set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `while` to

```
do {
    //old body here            
} while (rs.next())
```

This construction check condition after execution of the body. Effectively skipping first `next` call.

You may want to check result of `rs.absolute(startRow)`. If it `false` then result set contains less than `startRow` rows.

Comment: I tried that already as I told in my question. But then lets say that I have a query with "where" (to shrink the results) then sometimes it throws exhausted resultset exception.

Comment: @csel It happens because resultset doesn't have `startRow` row.

Comment: @csel added note about how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting at startRow + 1 because you set rs.next after rs.absolute. Just change this and it will work.

```
String SQL_QUERY = select * from my_table;
Statement stt = null;
stt= conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
            ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(SQL_QUERY);
if (rs != null) {
rs.absolute(startRow); // here you are at row startRow
} 

while(rs.next()){
// and here you are at row startRow + 1
}
```